# Java - Splitting string by backslash (\)

Tags: java, arrays, string, date, split

I'm trying to split a string by a backslash but I'm having problems. I'm sure I have the expression right can someone read what I've done and tell me my problem?

---

```
package taskstodo;

public class Task {
    StringBuilder name;
    StringBuilder note;
    StringBuilder date;

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = new StringBuilder(name);
    }
    void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = new StringBuilder(note);
    }
    boolean dateIsValid() {
        String dateStr = date.toString();
        String[] numbers = (dateStr.split("[\\\\]"));
        for(String num : numbers) {
            System.out.println(num);
            if ((num.length()) != 2) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = new StringBuilder(date);
    }
}
```

---

package taskstodo;

public class TasksToDo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task myTask = new Task();
    myTask.setDate("02/03/20");
    System.out.println(myTask.dateIsValid());
    Task myTask2 = new Task();
    myTask2.setDate("23/45/6001");
    System.out.println(myTask2.dateIsValid());
}
```

}

---

The TasksToDo class tests the Task class.

It should return:

```
02
03
20
true
23
45
6001
false
```

But it returns:

```
02/03/20
false
23/45/6001
false
```

Comment: The delimiter should be "/" and not "\" no?

Comment: Could just have dyslexia, you know.

Comment: You should validate the date format with a regexp instead :-)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say you want to split by backslash `\` but you're passing in forward slash `/` to your test case. How can you expect it to work?!

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task myTask = new Task();
    myTask.setDate("02\\03\\20");
    System.out.println(myTask.dateIsValid());
    Task myTask2 = new Task();
    myTask2.setDate("23\\45\\6001");
    System.out.println(myTask2.dateIsValid());
}
```

Comment: Thank You! How did I miss that? Thanks :)

Comment: @sudsiv It happens all the time in IT :)

Answer (score 1):

To check your date you can let the Jdk doing the parsing for you .

```
try
        {
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("21/16/2000");
            return true;
        }
        catch ( ParseException exception )
        {
            return false;
        }
```